# Regarding GC Reminder Notifications Not Working

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-calendar-reminders

I have integrated my PHP application with Google Calendar using my service account.

The event creation through my application is working successfully.

I am trying to override the events reminder settings through the override method as follows.

```
 $event = new \Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
                'summary' => 'My App Appointment Reminders2',              
                'description' => 'My App Reminders',
                'start' => array(
                'dateTime' => $start['dateTime'],
                'timeZone' => $zone,
                ),
                'end' => array(
                'dateTime' => $end['dateTime'],
                'timeZone' => $zone,
                ),
                'attendees' => array(
                array('email' => 'example@gmail.com'),
                )
                ,
                'reminders' => array(
                'useDefault' => false
                 ,
                  'overrides' => array(
                  array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 15),
                  array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 15),
                  ),
            ),
            ));
```

I have also used the string instead of boolean for Usedefault. Still it is not working

Please help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

### This issue has been [reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/141903683) on Google's Public Issue Tracker and is under investigation

The issue is related to using a service account when performing requests with the Calendar API. 
In the meantime, as a workaround:

- Do NOT use a service account without [impersonation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#impersonating_a_service_account)
- Instead, enable [domain-wide delegeation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account) and let the service account impersonate a domain user who has editor access to the calendar
- In PHP you can perform impersonation with
  `$client->setSubject('user to impersonate');`
- See [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#delegatingauthority) for samples